# How should I use Lambda expression to evaluate maximum integer out of a collection of strings?

Tags: lambda

I have observablecollection of strings. I would like to find out the maximum of integer in that observablecollection using a Lambda expression.

**Example:** If my collection is: {stringOC[2], stringOC[1], stringOC[7], stringOC[3]}, and I want to find the largest integer, then I'd get 7.

Comment: Can you please rewrite your collection example so that it is compilable code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to select first and within the select, convert to an `int`

```
string[] strings = ...;
int maximum = strings.ToList().Select(str => Convert.ToInt32(str)).Max();
```